# Solve this inequality with $G_j-H_j\geqslant C(G_i-H_i).$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

For a sequence of positive reals $(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, denote the geometric mean and harmonic mean of its first $n$ terms as $G_n$ and $H_n$ respectively. 
For given integers $j>i>1$, determine the largest real $C=C(i,j)$ such that for any $(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, if $2x_n\geqslant G_n+H_n$, then $$G_j-H_j\geqslant C(G_i-H_i).$$

I  guess $C_{\max}=\dfrac{i}{j}$. 
I guessed the answer from a probability point of view.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by $C(i,j)$? Where did you find this question?

Comment: @OliverJones $C$ depends just on $i$ and $j$